# How can I cache a downloaded ISO with Terraform?

Tags: terraform, libvirt

Is there a way I can cache an ISO being downloaded?

Right now if I `terraform destroy`, and `terraform apply` it'll once again download the ISO.

I'm using the `libvirt` provider and the related resource is:

```
resource "libvirt_volume" "ubuntu-qcow3" {
  name   = "ubuntu-qcow3"
  pool   = "default"
  source = "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/xenial/release/ubuntu-16.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img"
  format = "qcow2"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could download the image manually to a specific location (e.g. `/opt/images`)

```
wget https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04/release/ubuntu-16.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img -P /opt/images
```

and simply refer to this path, since `source` accepts local paths as well as remote urls:

```
resource "libvirt_volume" "ubuntu-qcow3" {
  name   = "ubuntu-qcow3"
  pool   = "default"
  source = "/opt/images/ubuntu-16.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img"
  format = "qcow2"
}
```

Seems very usefull for testing purpose. I learned it from [this tutorial](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-provision-vms-on-kvm-with-terraform/) where using local file paths was commented out. Since I don't want to mix config files with binary images, I moved them to `/opt` but feel free to place them where you like.

Comment: I've found if you download the images direct from a URL it's crazy slow. For me it was 20 mins with wget vs 2.5hrs for the URL before I gave up. I have no idea how much longer it would have taken.